# Changing ContextMenu Appearance

Tags: c#, wpf

currently I have the basic radgridview Context menu, I'm trying to get it to look like the context menu in here from this demo [ContextMenu](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/contextmenu/defaultcs.aspx)

May I get some tips or suggestions, I'm not quite sure where to start.

My Contextmenu code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
         <MenuItem Header="View Contact" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Open()]"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking for a direction here.
I would suggest you to read about Styles and templates in WPF ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

In WPF the controls are view-less. The view is controlled by the style/template that you apply to the control.

For instance, in your case if you can get the style of the Context menu control you have mentioned (say it's named "FancyContextMenu" in resource dictionary).

Then you just need to modify your code to below:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FancyContextMenu}">....
```